# Codeigniter deleting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having fun with codeigniter but having an annoying little problem at the moment though, when trying to delete an item I get ” Message: Undefined property: Site::$url ” my only guess can be that something is not right with the url helper being included? I am autoloading it in the config.

this is my delete function in the model

```
 function delete_record()
 {
  $this->db->where('id', $this->url->segment(3));
  $this->db->delete('items');

 }
```

here I am calling it in the view:

```
<?php echo $row->subject; ?> <?php echo anchor("site/delete/$row->id","Delete");?>
```

this is the controller:

```
function delete(){
  $this->Site_model->delete_record();
  $this->index();
  }
```

and just to make sure I am not doing anything wrong.. this is in autoload in the config:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Much appreciated for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no url class.

You want to switch `$this->url->segment(3)` to `$this->uri->segment(3)` noting the I instead of the L.

The url **helper** is for generating site urls, etc. The URI class is an integral part of the CI core so it is always loaded.

[URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

[URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

It must be

```
$this->uri->segment(3) not $this->url->segment(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes u hav to made:

FIRST:

```
$this->url->segment(3) to $this->uri->segment(3);
```

SECOND:In the view

```
<?php echo $row->subject; ?> <?php echo anchor("site/delete/".$row->id,"Delete");?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you done is all right just replace the 'url' to 'uri',like this.

```
$this->url->segment(3) to $this->uri->segment(3) //replace url to uri.
```